# Displacement of electron in magnetic and electric field, verification of one logic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, work

I have solved this problem, but just need verification of my thinking about this as well as the question book has used full page for solution(using simple harmonic) but I had done it in a rather different and quicker way

Q-- An electron is released from origin where a uniform electric field exists in negative y direction and a uniform magnetic field in z direction find its displacement from y axis line when velocity of electron is perpendicular to electric field for the first time (see the diagram blue lines are electric field ones
  crosses  in x-y plane represents magnetic field )
[image: I hope it is clear]

my logic that I have used to solve it(the answer comes out to be correct using this logic)----------------- since work done by magnetic field on any charged particle inside it is $0$
       so only work done is by electric field

by work energy theorem----

$\int eEdy$ $=$ $\frac{mv^2}{2}$----1 (no work done by magnetic force is considered) Note :- $e$ is charge of electron

**it is from logic that the magnetic force is always perpendicular to charge velocity, hence its displacement so  work done by it must be $0$ in this case as well isn't it ?       so the above equation --1 is correct or not??? I guess it correct as answer comes out to be same**

*if I am correct then it would save my brain as well as time from being wrecked by the full page mind boggling solution that the book has stated
and as I said earlier I had solved it , I just want to verify my logic , as the book took a huge difficult solution to answer it , any help would save me*

Comment: AS Mr. Singh points out, you are looking for the change in x.  How is that found from your equation?

Comment: @R.W.Bird This was not the only equation, there were other equations as well but not of SHM like, when i will have time i will answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> magnetic force is always perpendicular to charge velocity, hence its displacement so work done by it must be $0$ in this case

This is indeed true. The work done by the magnetic force in this case is $0$ since, it is always perpendicular to the displacement of the particle.

The expression that you have formed for calculating velocity using Work Energy theorem also looks correct, since the work is done only by the electric field.